# creating a classified - stuck

Tags: php, mysql

I am a beginner in web designing (php, mysql). I am creating a classified similar to Craigslist but not as complex.

I managed to get the user ad input as well as pics inserted into mysql databases and everything is working perfectly.

I also managed to fetch the data when a user searches a specific category like cars

```
    $query="SELECT city, title, price FROM md_post WHERE category='cars'";

$result= mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<a href='XXXX.php'>". $row['title']. " - ". $row['price']." - ".$row['city']."</a>";
echo "<br /><br />";
```

OUTPUT IS:
Charlotte - NISSAN - $9000
Charlotte - BMW - $11000

what i want now is, when a user clicks on a title ad, the user is redirected to the ad page itself. ( just the like what Craigslist or any classified would do)

how can I do this? I know it is a general questions and i am not expecting anybody to provide a whole code but i need hints and ideas please.

I will be very grateful. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need the records in your database to have a unique field that is auto_incrementing (counting up automatically when a new row is inserted).

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

When you select your ads from the database, you can take the ID for that ad out of the database at the same time

```
$query="SELECT ad_id, city, title, price FROM md_post WHERE category='cars'";
```

Then get the ad_id in the same way `$row['ad_id']`.

You could then post this straight in to your HTML  tag to form a URL like: `ad.php?id={ID OF AD HERE}`

```
echo "<a href='ad.php?id=' . $row['ad_id'] . '>". $row['title']. " - ". $row['price']." - ".$row['city']."</a>";
```

Then in your ad.php you can pic this ID up using

```
echo $_GET['id'];
```

You can use this ID in a query to select the correct ad... but make sure if you're selecting from your database to use `mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id'])` to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. sorry i forgot to include and mention my auto increment post_id. I do have it and every row in mysql have a post_id. But I am having difficulty in assigning a page like www.x.com/?id=xxx to each post. I will give it a try using the method you mentioned. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @MohammedA.AlJama Great stuff, have a go!  To get you started, create a new PHP page, then just insert `<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>` then visit the `phppage.php?id=hello` `phppage.php?id=12345` and then you'll see that the value you specify will be passed to the script.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have been coding for a week like crazy to build this website and I am learning so much everyday. Thanks for your support and help. This will keep me going always forward.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the address of the ad_page just put it inside your href

```
$query="SELECT city, title, price FROM md_post WHERE category='cars'";

$result= mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $ad_page = ..;
    echo "<a href="'.$ad_page.'">". $row['title']. " - ". $row['price']." - ".$row['city']."</a>";
    echo "<br /><br />";
}
```

if it comes from your db, just put it into your query.. or what else..

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I still do not have my ad_page. For some reason, I am having difficulty in assigning a page like www.x.com/?id=xxx to each post.. If I do this, referring the title to this post page should be easy as you mentioned above.